# Dispatch action is missing in props validation [react/prop-types]

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm getting es lint error like this
[eslint] 'getBrodcastedList' is missing in props validation [react/prop-types]

```
import { PropTypes } from 'react';
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {


getRequests(query) {
    this.props.getList(query);//this line  [eslint] 'getList' is missing in props validation [react/prop-types]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloMessage name="Taylor" />,
  document.getElementById('hello-example')
);
```

help me. how do i define a prop types for this
es lint error on --> "this.props.getList(query)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do add propTypes for `getList` method.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class HelloMessage extends React.Component {

getRequests(query) {
    this.props.getList(query);//this line  [eslint] 'getList' is missing in props validation [react/prop-types]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

HelloMessage.propTypes = {
  getList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Note: You need to install another package `prop-types` for it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should define your function ES6 syntax to be able access to this.props, this.state inside:
   Change "getRequests(query){...}" to "getRequests = (query) => {...}"
2. Define PropsType for your component:

> ```
> HelloMessage.propTypes = {      
>     getList: PropTypes.func.isRequired
> };
> ```

[Typechecking With PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)